# OpenCV - RETR_EXTERNAL not working after Otsu's binarization

Tags: python, opencv, contour

I have applied the Otsu's binarization to one image and got this result

[image]

After that, I use this code to get boxes around the four main shapes:

```
img = cv.imread('test_bin.jpg', 0)
_, cnts, _ = cv.findContours(img.copy(), cv.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

for cnt in cnts:
    x,y,w,h = cv.boundingRect(cnt)
    cv.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,255,0),2)

cv.imwrite('test_cnt.jpg', img)
```

However, I'm not getting anything. It returns just one contour which I imagine it could be the full image itself. I saw it works for RETR_TREE, but I need it to work with RETR_EXTERNAL for the next operations. What is failing here?

Answer (score 1):

As per the OpenCV contours [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/3.3.1/d4/d73/tutorial_py_contours_begin.html):

> In OpenCV, finding contours is like finding white object from black
>   background. So remember, object to be found should be white and
>   background should be black.

But in your case, it is clearly the opposite of the requirements, so you just need to invert your image and it can be simply done as:

```
img = cv2.bitwise_not(img)
```

Also, note that:

> For better accuracy, use binary images. So before finding contours,
>   apply threshold or canny edge detection.

I used your image and got following results, after inverting the image. If you want to remove the small boxes, then simply use `cv2.threshold` to get a binary image.

[image]